# Second Isomorphism Theorem and Jordan-Holder

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

In another posting, there was a question about the following:

Let $G$ be a finite non-trivial group with the following two composition series:

$\{e\} = M_0 \triangleleft M_1 \triangleleft M_2 = G$

$\{e\} = N_0 \triangleleft N_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft N_r = G.$

Prove that $r=2$ and that $G/M_1 \cong G/N_1$ and $N_1/N_0 \cong M_1/M_0$.

The person posting the question went on to state that "By the second isomorphism theorem I know that $M_1N_2/N_2 \cong M_1/(N_2\cap M_1)$"

Here is my question.  In order to use the second isomorphism theorem with $M_1$ and $N_2$ don't we need to know that $M_1 \leq N_G(N_2)$?  And if so, then how do we know that $M_1$ actually is in the normalizer of $N_2$ in $G$?

If I can get over this hurdle, I understand the remainder of the original posting.  Perhaps this is something obvious, but please help me see whatever it is that I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you are talking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513697/), both the question and the accepted answer are problematic.

Comment: Yes, that is the posting that prompted me to ask my question.

Comment: That indeed doesn't work.  What works is that $N_2/(N_2\cap M_1)\cong N_2M_1/M_1$ since $M_1\lhd G$.  But of course the original question is problematic because Jordan-Holder only give same quotients up to reordering and it is clearly possible to have factors in different order, e.g. $1\lhd C_2\lhd C_6$ and $1\lhd C_3\lhd C_6$.